# How to test directory reading and addressing method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a ruby class to read directory and do something for each file. But I am not sure how to test it.

```
class Scanner
  def scan(dir)
    Dir.glob(File.join(dir, '**', '*')).each do |path|
       verify(path)
    end
  end

  private 

  def verify(path)
    do something for the file...
  end
end
```

I want to have a unit-testing for `scan` method.

- Should I mock something?
- Should I provide a test directory in `spec/fixtures`?
- What's the expectation?

Cheers

Comment: The only thing that does not come from ruby core (standard lib) in `scan` is `verify`. You should test `verify` and that’s it. You should not test ruby core.

Comment: Your scanner has two responsibilities: listing files and doing something to them. Likely would be easier to test if you split this into two entities.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: "the only thing... is `verify`" - that, and the literals (configuration for `glob`). I agree, testing core sounds like a waste of time, but one should test their business logic.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev are you paid for LOCs you produce? :) `Dir#glob` and `Enumerable#each` do indeed work.

Comment: “one should test their business logic”—correct. I assume this `scan` is called from the business logic unit and that is what requires a test. The `scan` itself is the implementation detail (besides it is provided by ruby stdlib.)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: the power of abstraction, once you feel it, it's hard to not try use it everywhere. In fact, every problem can be solved by adding a level of astraction. Except the problem of too many levels of abstraction. :)

Comment: The “problem of too many levels of abstraction” might be easily shifted by introducing meta-abstraction :-P

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to approach that. One (proposed in the comments) is to separate the concerns, e.g.

```
class Scanner
  def scan(dir)
    Dir.glob(File.join(dir, '**', '*')).each do |path|
       verify(path)
    end
  end

  private 

  def verify(path)
    Veryfier.new.verify(File.read(path))
    # you can test veryfier easily by passing different strings into `verify` method
  end
end
```

And go on with your life, as `Scanner#scan` is not that complicated anymore, and one would not expect many bugs in there.

But, if for whatever reason, you want it tested as well, you can do one of the following:

- set up a dir structure under `test/features` and tread different directories like different cases. This has one drawback: you have to inspect directories plus read the tests to understand the tests. But it's simple to do.
- use Dir.tmpdir and File.tmpfile to set up the dir structure inside your tests. This is a bit more involved, but on the plus side you have the structure and the tests for behavior of the `Scanner` in a single test file.